# linphonecore.setPlayLevel() does nothing?

Tags: android, linphone

I'm using the linphone sip library to build an android voip app. I see a function called LinphoneCore.setPlayLevel() but i'm not sure what it does.  I tried using it but it seems to have no effect.

Does anyone know what it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so both setPlayLevel() and getPlayLevel() do absolutely nothing.

I took a look at the core code file `submodules/linphone/java/impl/org/linphone/core/LinphoneCoreImpl.java` only to find these placeholder function that do nothing and return nothing useful.

```
    public int getPlayLevel() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
    }
    public void setPlayLevel(int level) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

linphone team should update their api documentation and say these functions are deprecated